# The most condensed / shortest way to append a new line to a file

Tags: c#, .net, windows

There are various method of appending text to files, although I was wondering if any knows the shortest way to do this

e.g. Add a new line to an existing txt file:

```
line1
line2
<new-line-here>
```

Comment: Did you mean append a new line of text, or newline character(s)? There are answers for both questions mixed in here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That would be something like:

```
File.AppendAllText("c:\filepath.txt", "text to append");
```

See [File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx) for details. The [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z2ck8eh.aspx) class has a lot of useful static methods for doing common file operations.

Comment: @driis: Append all text does not necessarily add a new line.

Comment: "Append all text does not necessarily add a new line" - it does if you ask it nicely.

Comment: @M.Babcock What if you do `File.AppendAllText("c:\filepath.txt", String.Format("{0}text to append", Environment.NewLine));`?

Comment: @michielvoo: That will work but if the file is empty before the append it will then contain a blank line at the top.

Answer (score 8):

The File class's static methods make it fairly straight forward:

```
File.AppendAllLines("filename.txt", new[] { "text to append" });
```

**Edit:** Using an array is slightly shorter.

Comment: Actually this should be accepted. Even though you need to pass in an IEnumerable to `AppendAllLines`, it's always going to be shorter than `AppendAllText`. With `AppendAllText` you need to add `Environment.NewLine` as well. Which takes more characters than `new string []{}`...

Answer (score 3):

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllText("some file", Environment.NewLine);
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: Will not be an complete line break, should be "\n\r" or Environment.NewLine. (char 10 and 13 i think in ascii)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(file_path);
sw.WriteLine("appended text");
```

Source = http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext.aspx

Comment: The StreamWriter should get disposed.

Answer (score 2):

```
 System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"c:\test.txt",Environment.NewLine);
```

Is the right way to do it, just \n wont do it !